# Arrow keys randomly stop working in x2go

Tags: keyboard, x2go, x2goclient

I am connecting from Ubuntu Linux 18 to another Ubuntu linux machine with x2go. Connection works, but some keys don't, especially arrow keys. When I press up arrow, it starts screen capture:

[image]

I tried some recipes from this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/582552/x2go-arrow-key-is-not-working-properly
but they don't help. **setxkbmap us -print | xkbcomp - $DISPLAY** -- doesn't fix the problem. I tried to play with keyboard settings here:

[image]

but it doesn't help also. How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**: my x2go client version is:

[image]

x2go server version: x2goserver/bionic,now 4.1.0.0-3 amd64

**UPDATE 2** I've followed instruction from wiki.x2go.org updating x2goclient to 4.1.2.2-0~1913~ubuntu18.04.1 and x2goserver to 4.1.0.3-0~1708~ubuntu18.04.1. The problem is still there.

Comment: which x2go versions on the client and the server ? please update your answer with this info

Comment: @RobertRiedl, i've supplied desired information

Comment: While they are not hugely outdated, there are newer versions available: `4.1.2.0`on the client side and `4.1.0.3` on the server. They are availbale in the [official x2go stable repo](https://launchpad.net/%7Ex2go/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75). Here is a [short howto](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:ubuntu) install using the repot

Comment: Please comment, if an upgrade to the newest versions has solved the issue

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is hard to reproduce, i.e. without upgrade it happens only some times. I'll let you know.

Comment: Update didn't solve the problem.

Comment: damn,... well it was worth a try

Comment: Can I contact you Robert to help me fix that somehow?

Comment: beyond askubuntu you mean ? This is the correct platform. Unfortunately, this is very difficult to solve since even you cannot recreate it reliably.  Even then, it does sound more like a bug to me - thats why I suggested the current version. It may be something todo with stuck 3rd layer/alt ? As soon as you have either a way to reproduce this or some kind of log/error message or any other insights, we can continue here.

Comment: I resolved the issue with logout/login on remote PC.

Comment: This is temporary solution, i'd like to admit...

Answer (score 0):

Not so much of a resolution, but definitely a fix.  Read on.

I routinely use X2GoClient on Linux and Windows against same sessions on Linux boxes.  Every time I use the Windows version, one or two keys don't work.  It's usually a special key, like one of the arrow keys, backspace, or delete and is not consistent for the most part, but for the past month it has been that the delete key doesn't work inside the session.  Once I used the Linux client, the problem sometimes would go away and sometimes wouldn't.  Couldn't solve it, but finally got around it by using Autokey (apt install autokey-qt or autokey-gtk) and mapping the "delete" key to "".  I suspect it'll work for other keys as well.